# How to convert binary numpy image into vertices

Tags: python, numpy

I have searched everywhere but I can't find a good solution to this problem. So any help would be much appreciated.

Lets say there is a binary array that looks something like this

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I would like to find vertices of this array so that the output will be something like this

```
[[3 7]
 [8 7]
 [8 2]
 [3 2]
 [3 7]]
```

There might be multiple of polygons on a single binary image. 
Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: To me what you want is to use openCV and the findcontours function

Comment: @Sabrina if I understand the problem correctly there should be only 4 vertices right? Your return statement seems to have non-unique vertices.

Comment: @AdityaLahiri There will be 5 vertices because it should return a closed polygon. The last point should be always the same as the first one.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! I think I know how to solve it now.